# trigger.io topbar issue IOS

Tags: ios, module, trigger.io

The current module for the top bar breaks in IOS 6, reverting to a previous version makes it work again but will not work in IOS 7.

What I see is when I open the app with the new topbar and tabbar is the "hide" command does not seem to be hiding the header and footer, causing them to show while the loading screen is still showing (this happens in both IOS 6 and 7), then they will seem to hide only after the few seconds once the app is loaded.

Next the topBar does not seem to get tinted (stays black ) in IOS 6 and the webview seems to be off, in IOS 7 this seems to be ok but 6 its not working.

**Edit 1:**

After doing some additonal research it seems the app is crashing and throwing this error.

Oct  6 16:29:33 Michaels-iPhone Forge[341] : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWit

This app has been working just fine on pervious versions and now for some reason is crashing

**Edit 2:**

So it seems there is a problem with both the header and footer modules (topBar and TabBar) where with IOS 6 they are just not working correctly. If I revert them to the previous version they work just fine for IOS (Will be testing 7 soon)

Next the error I was getting that seemed to be crashing things had to do with the request module, again if I revert that back one version I do not get the crashing I was seeing. Not sure why it was causing it to crash but like I said move it one version lower fixed the issues. I even double check it where I lowered it, ran it and had no crash, added it back in and got the crash, then removed it again and the crashing was gone.

**Edit 3:**

So I tested IOS 7 with the current settings I have and as expected the header and footers are messed up, seeing as the updates were for IOS 7 I kind of expected this. What is strange is that if I download the app from itunes the header and footer bars work just fine in IOS 7 but they have the old style of rendering. I will try to pre-render later on and see if it helps.

**Edit 4:**

Still no update from trigger.io on this obvious bug, I have been able to get the topbar to tint by making the core version set to 2.03 ( what seems odd is that forge says the default version is 2.01 but in the drop down I see 2.03 and the docs online show 2.03 as the most current but 2.01 says the "stable" version ) While I can get that working the tabbars are still not functioning properly as it seems to mess with the size of the webview between the header and footer. What is the really sucky part is I have updates that need to be made but here I am a week without an answer from trigger.io, how are we suppose to put faith in a company to build our apps if they put out an update with bugs that they seem unwilling to address or fix?

**Edit 5:**

To give a little more info for James this is what happens with different versions

**scenario 1):**

All modules up to date
Core version 2.0.3
IOS6 version (6.1.3)

TopBar and Tabbar show over launch image, once launch image is gone bars will no longer show. ( I have a hide event in place to hide them until a user logs into the the app )

Once the user has logged into the app the webview is messed up, almost like its calculating the height of the page without the tabbar and topbar in place so when it displays the page is not at the top but 100 to 150 px offset from the top

As stated this is with every module up to date and core at 2.0.3

**scenario 2):**

TopBar module 2.1 and tabbar module 2.0
All other modules are up to date
Core version 2.0.3
IOS6 version (6.1.3)

When loading up the app the topBar shows over the splash screen but the tab-bar does not, once logged into the app the same webview issues happens, offset by 100 to 150 px

**scenario 3):**

TopBar module 2.0 and tabbar module 2.0
All other modules are up to date
Core version 2.0.3
IOS6 version (6.1.3)

With this config everything seems to work ok, the topbar and tabbar do not show over the launch image, once inside the app the webview is correct and everything seems to work as expected but then a different issue comes up, the app will crash on the forge request, hence this error

Oct 6 16:29:33 Michaels-iPhone Forge[341] : * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWit

I cannot explain why the request module would work for logging into the app and making other request and then just suddenly fail, I do know though that if I change the request module back to the previous version I experience no issues with IOS 6

**scenario 4):**

TopBar module 2.0 , tabbar module 2.0, and request module 2.0 
All other modules are up to date
Core version 2.0.3
IOS6 version (6.1.3)

Success! We have the app working as it should in IOS 6, no top or tab bar problems, no webview issues and no crashing.

This is great lets see how it looks on IOS 7..

**scenario 5):**

TopBar module 2.0 , tabbar module 2.0, and request module 2.0 
All other modules are up to date
Core version 2.0.3
IOS7 version (7.0)

When I open the app the launch screen comes up, then goes away somewhat quickly and reveals the topbar and tabbar, almost like its going away too quickly and its just a white screen with a topbar and tabbar.

once I log into the app the topbar and tabbar seem to be cut off, like the are the right height but the margin inside the bar is set to like -50px so the bar itself gets pushed up and cut off.

**scenario 6):**

TopBar module 2.2 , tabbar module 2.1, and request module 2.0 
All other modules are up to date
Core version 2.0.3
IOS7 version (7.0)

Opening up the app we see the splash screen but again the splash screen seems to hide too quickly revealing the topbar and tabbar with a white screen, then it places you into the app.

Once logged into the app things look as they should

**scenario 7):**

All modules up to date
Core version 2.0.3
IOS7 version (7.0)

We have placed every module and core to be up to date, same launch screen issues as in scenario 5 and 6 but don't see the crashing issue as before.

**Edit 6**

I Just tested out the hide manualy and it does not seem to be working with IOS 7, it just seems to ignore the hide manually command

This is snippet from the config.json

`"modules": {
        "launchimage": {
            "version": "2.1",
            "config": {
                "android-landscape": "androidLand.png",
                "background-color": "#000000",
                "android": "androidPort.png",
                "ios": {
                    "1536x2048": "img/splash/1536X2048.png",
                    "320x480": "img/splash/320x480px.png",
                    "640x1136": "img/splash/640x1136px.png",
                    "2048x1536": "img/splash/2048x1536px.png",
                    "1536x2008": "img/splash/1536x2008px.png",
                    "1024x768": "img/splash/1024X748.png",
                    "2048x1496": "img/splash/2048x1496px.png",
                    "1024x748": "img/splash/1024X768.png",
                    "640x960": "img/splash/640x960px.png",
                    "768x1004": "img/splash/768x1004px.png",
                    "768x1024": "img/splash/768x1024px.png"
                },
                "hide-manually": true
            }`

To double check this I tried it in ios6 and it does work, what I see in IOS 7 is the splash screen shows up for about 1 second, then goes away to reveal a white screen and the header and footer then loads up my webview completely ignoring the hide manually command. I tried with IOS 6 and the hide manually works, the way I tested this just to be sure is to completely remove the hide manually call in my code (so it would not hide) and on IOS 6 its not hiding as expected but ios 7 seems to blow right past that and hide the screen.

**Edit 7**
Seems there are some updates to the modules for tab and top bar.. will give it a shot!

Comment: +1 I'm encountering the same issues. Further to your comment in Edit 4 re: "size of the webview between the header and footer" I found that window.innerHeight no longer returns the correct value when using topbar v2.2: would need to subtract topbar height from window.innerHeight to get the correct value, but since there is no method provided to get the height of the topbar it looks like we're stuck for now...

Comment: Hi guys, can you include your `config.json` for an app which is exhibiting these issues? Testing v2.0.3 platform with topbar 2.2 here, and not seeing the launchimage interaction you describe on iOS 6 or 7.

Comment: James, where should we send it to? 

Also just to confirm we should be using 2.0.3 correct, as forge states this is not the sable version. If I set to 2.0.3 and update all to the current then the webview is messed up, if I downgrade the tab bar to previous it works in IOS6 but IOS 7 is not working

The launch Image issue seems to be resolved when you switch to 2.3 but the tabbar becomes an issue with IOS 6. I can send a screenshot if you like, it just seems like they are not compatable with each other.

Comment: James, please see the updates to the main post with the different scenarios I have added for edit 5

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try to summarise this into 5 issues - let me know if I missed anything!

1. on iOS 6.1, the topbar and tabbar show over the launchimage
2. the window height as reported by webview (or placement of top of page?) is incorrect
3. the request module can cause an `NSInvalidArgumentException`
4. 2.0 versions of tabbar and topbar don't work with iOS 7
5. the launchimage hides too quickly on iOS 7

**1**: Can you include screenshots, and your config.json, in the question (or, see https://trigger.io/forge/support/ to send directly)? I'm not seeing the behaviour you describe: the topbar and tabbar are invisible until the launchimage hides.

**2**: Are you using `window.innerHeight` or similar to layout your app? Or do you mean that straightforward HTML is being laid out incorrectly? A screenshot would be great, along with a stripped down code sample if possible.

**3**: Could we split this off into a separate SO question? It's almost certainly unrelated to the thrust of this question. In that, samples of `config.json` and code would be great.

**4**: iOS 7 support was included in the 2.1 versions of those modules: 2.0 will not behave properly on iOS 7. See https://trigger.io/modules/_/changelog/.

**5**: If it's just that your app needs a bit more time to initialise, you can use the "Hide Manually" option for launchimage (https://trigger.io/modules/launchimage/current/docs/index.html)

Comment: 1) **I don't have a go big plan, how can I send these items?**
2) I use window.innerHeight for some things but like I said it was never an issue before
3) I am fine with that, what do you want the other question to be?
4) I saw that in the change log and it was mainly to show how down grading to a previous version resolved the issue with ios6 but 7 was not working somewhat concluding that something added to those modules caused the issue with IOS6 
5) I tried this in the past and it did not seem to work but I will give it another shot and see if this fixes the issue

Thanks

Comment: @proxim0 if it's worth anything, regarding, item 5 - I can report this has worked for us in the past quite well.

Comment: @Horak I should have worded that better, I have used the hide splash screen before, to be honest it was my default setting for a while but in previous testing it did not seem to fix the issue but like I said I'm going off memory at this point and will confirm in just a few :)

Comment: @James Brady So I just tested the manual hide for IOS 7 and it does not seem to work. I checked it on IOS 6 and it does work. Look at my update for how I tested it

Comment: @James Brady: Any update on this? It's rather crippling our business