# TabBar and TopBar bug in iOS 6 and 7

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am experiencing a crippling bug on iOS 6 and 7 with the TopBar and TabBar modules.
It appears that the view does not shrink, leaving the body at the same height as without it (example: 320 pixel phone screen, the body will still be 320 pixels). 
Even an empty webpage will scroll, even if the body height is 0 (from Safari DOMInspector);

In addition, when we use angularjs to show our view, the first 20-30 pixels are "scrolled" behind the topbar until the user scrolls up.

Any idea?

Comment: Think this might be fixed by using (just released) topbar 2.3 and tabbar 2.2 modules, could you try these out and comment?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues that trigger.io seems to just ignore. I have somewhat of a lengthy post on that issue and some others here

[trigger.io topbar issue IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214008/trigger-io-topbar-issue-ios)

Maybe if enough people complain about it they will address the issue